# Как правильно гуглить?

Tags: поиск, браузер, информация

Как правильно гуглить чтобы всегда находить ответы:)

Answer (score 1):

Основные советы можно найти в справке самого Google в статье ["Как пользоваться поиском в Google"](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/134479?hl=ru).
Больше об интересных возможностях поиска можно прочитать в [этой статье на adme.ru](https://www.adme.ru/zhizn-nauka/10-sposobov-ispolzovat-poisk-google-kak-nastoyaschij-professional-1225160/), например, как искать по синонимам, с пропущенными словами, фразу целиком, по определенному сайту и т.д или [на Хабре](https://habr.com/ru/sandbox/46956/) про разные операторы, которые можно использовать, чтобы сделать поисковый запрос максимально точным и эффективным.
Успехов!